# Access device in two different subnets

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have these two subnets in my home network.
Subnet 1 is the main network with fast internet & reliable internet connection.
Subnet 2 is connected via a VPN tunnel abroad. Subnet 2 is mainly used for watching geo-blocked TV.

Subnet 1

```
Router: Livebox
Router IP: 192.168.1.1
DHCP range: 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Internet: Connected directly, ISP in France (400Mbps)
Wi-Fi : yes
```

Subnet 2

```
Router: Netgear Nighthawk running Tomato 
VPN Client: Connected VPN Server in Sweden (10Mbps)
Router IP: 192.168.9.1
DHCP range: 192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.254
Internet: Connected to the Netgear router via cable
WAN IP: 192.168.1.12
Wi-Fi : yes
```

A voice control system is installed on subnet 1 together with lights, shades SONOS etc. The TV is often connected to subnet 2 (Wi-Fi). The voice control system cannot access the TV (not possible to select channel/mute etc by voice)

Question: What are my options to allow a device on subnet 1 to access to the TV on subnet 2, given the set-up with the VPN tunnel?

So far, I have tried bridging with a SONOS Play 5(by connecting Wi-Fi and LAN to subnet 1&2), to set the IP range of both subnets to the same range 192.168.1.x (without overlapping). No luck so far.

Comment: "What are my options to allow a device on subnet 1 to access to the TV on subnet 2, given the set-up with the VPN tunnel?" - Assign an IP address to the first router in the subnet of the second router but assigned devices connected to the first router to a different subnet. Or purchase a router capable of VLANs.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound

Comment: **Option 1.** *Assign an IP address to the first router in the subnet of the second router but assigned devices connected to the first router to a different subnet.*
As I understand you, I shall change the IP of the Livebox from 192.168.1.1 to e.g.: 192.168.9.100 (any free IP on Subnet 2) but keep the DHCP address range unchanged 192.168.1.x

**Option 2:**  The Livebox is not capable of VLAN. I will look into VLAN